# "The application bundle does not contain a valid identifier" error after installing socket mobile scan api sdk

Tags: ios, socketscan, socketmobile

After installing Socket Mobile Scan Api Sdk via cocoa pod, I couldn't run on real device anymore. I noticed the sdk include "Resources" group. But I couldn't able to run the project on real device even after renaming and deleting the "Resources" group. I'm using "scanapisdk-10-3-41 2" on Xcode 7.3.1 and trying to run on ipad Air 2.

Comment: Can you provide any additional information? Like, were you able to get the SingleEntry sample application to run on your device? What version of iOS? Do you have any other cocoapod dependencies installed? What about non-cocoapod dependencies?

Comment: Why would you rename or delete the Resources group? That's part of the SDK. Without more info I can only guess, but I assume you didn't install the pod correctly. I am using an older version of the SDK which came with a podspec not suitable for cocoapods 1.0, so I had to use cocoapods 0.39 to `pod install` it. However, your case seems different, as you could at least create the workspace (cocoapods 1.0 fails to do so with my version of the SDKs podspec). Please elaborate more on your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry for late reply. Actually I have already found workaround for the issue. It might not be correct solution but it works fine. After some successful attempts to install sdk on new projects I notice that my current project main target name has space. After renaming the target and re-install  the pod, I have no longer experienced this issue anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting the answer just in case if other people face the same problem in the future. As I commented in the original question. This issue is solved by removing space in the project target name 
(eg. `Sample Project` -> `SampleProject`). 
I'm not sure about what is the real reason causing the problem. However I don't face anymore issue after I re-name my project target.

**Edit** : I faced the problem again after installing another frameworks using cocoapods. But I managed to solve the problem with a workaround (re-naming target).